# Is it ok to have singleton + Provider in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm working on a Flutter app. I've a singleton GameManager that looks like:

```
class GameManager extends ChangeNotifier {
  static final GameManager _singleton = GameManager._internal();

  factory GameManager() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  GameManager._internal();
}
```

And in my entry point main.dart:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    GameManager().connect(isConnected: () {
      DynamicLinksService().initDynamicLinks();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<GameManager>(create: (context) => GameManager()),
      ],
    ...
  }
```

1. GameManager().connect() is making use of the singleton pattern.
2. I'm using Provider in main.dart and Consumer in my pages to listen to the state in GameManager.
3. I'm making it a singleton because connect() and provider that uses GameManager are both in main.dart and I want to call connect() in the entry point.
4. **Is it ok to have singleton + provider/consumer?** If not, is 5 a valid option?
5. Remove singleton. In my main page, call connect via consumer's GameManger.